# Tagging matrix as list

Tags: discussion, tagging

On [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8/how-to-symbolically-do-matrix-block-inversion) question on symbolic matrix block inversion, the [matrix](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/matrix) tag is used.

Typically in Mathematica literature references are made to Lists rather than Matrices. Matrices are just lists of lists after all.

What do you think of having [matrix](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/matrix) as a synonym for [list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/list) and using [list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/list) as the preferred form?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To expand on R.M's answer, I think [list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/list), [vector](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vector), [matrix](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/matrix), and [tensor](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tensor) could all be useful tags without being synonyms of a single tag.

Answer (score 8):

I disagree with having [matrix](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/matrix) as a *synonym* for [list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/list). A matrix is only a particular type of list, and as such, is not interchangeable in its usage. For example, you would never call `{1, {2, {3, {4}}}}` a matrix.

Comment: I wouldn't suggest that be a list. That's simply a list of lists. However a matrix is a list of lists with a certain structure.

Answer (score 4):

A matrix is a special case of a list, that is, it's two-dimensional and rectangular. Matrices have a lot of special functions designed for them, and they're often treated as the mathematical object that they are than just "some arrangement of numbers". Therefore, I wouldn't say it's a good idea to define a matrix to be a list.

(On a side note, most objects are simply lists, e.g. `Plot` generates a `Graphics` object containing a long list of options and values.)