# Can we have a central list for all the tagging decisions we make?

Tags: discussion, tagging, tag-synonyms, retagging

Szabolcs has suggested that we have a central place to note all our decisions about what questions should be tagged with which tag.

For example, we have decided that:

- [for graphics](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/86/8) ([see also here](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/a/21/8)) that the [graphics](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphics) tag applied wherever the user was going beyond the built-in visualisation commands like `Plot`. (See [tag wiki](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tags/graphics/info))
- [graphics](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphics) will suffice and can be used for 3D graphics too (no need for [graphics3d](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphics3d) (see [chat discussion](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2234/conversation/tags-graphics-or-graphics3d))
- questions solely about visualization functions and their options should use [plotting](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plotting).
- [evaluation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/evaluation) was more transparent than **evaluation-control** ([see chat discussion](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3079546#3079546))
- [questions about different versions](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/a/83/8) should be tagged [version-6](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/version-6), [version-7](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/version-7) and so on.
- [graphs, networks and Combinatorica-related questions](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/52/8) that should be tagged [graphs-and-networks](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphs-and-networks) to disambiguate from graphs in the plotting sense.
- [matrix](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/matrix) is not a synonym of [list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/list) and can be independently useful ([see meta discussion](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/23/8)).

See also: [central list of proposed tag synonyms](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/44/8).

Comment: great idea. I should help reduce/eliminate the confusion.

Comment: Per [Szabolcs](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/106/52) post, the purpose of this list is to record the decisions made by the community attaching the relevant links to the discussions. Correct?

Comment: @rcollyer Correct! And my intention was: it should be possible for only 3 people or so to make a decision, so we can move faster. Consulting the rest just means posting here.  Since it's a central place, everyone who cares can come and check once a day, and object to the decision if anything is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, we can! Please don't use this question to thrash out these issues, but rather, link each question (or chat transcript if needs be) to this central list, ideally in the question. It will then go community wiki.

Answer (score 0):

My reasoning was this:

Sometimes I have a suggestion or idea about tagging / synonyms.  I don't want to implement it before talking to others, so I ask a couple of people in chat.  But after that I'm still feeling insecure about putting the idea into practice.  What if someone has serious objections, but they didn't have a chance to learn about the proposed change yet?

Well, this list will make it easy for everyone to check what is happening on the site, and voice concerns.  If no one has objected to a suggestion for a day or so, people can feel confident about putting the changes into practice (e.g. retag question).

This way we can act much faster (avoid unnecessary hesitation) and still keep things organized and make sure that all concerns are heard.